# Tensorflow seq2seq with buckets using too much memory

Tags: tensorflow

I have this code: http://pastebin.com/7kcFekKG which is mostly copied from the unit tests of tensorflow and creates a seq2seq attention model with buckets. It works fine if i let the test code run but if i increase the sequence length to the values shown in the pastebin version it uses over 8gb of memory which is not really good for an rnn with 96 neurons. especially because i wanted to increase the number of neurons aswell. Is there anything im doing wrong which causes tf to use so much memory? i already tried to use a different aggegationmethod but debugging shows that the memory gets consumed when the network itself is created in line 47